# How to show a normal UWP window with C++ WinRT Console Application template

Tags: uwp, c++-winrt

I am trying to understand the full process of how does a UWP app work from scratch, so I want to reproduce the process with the C++ WinRT console application and want to create a window with XAML in it (just like a normal C++ WinRT blank page template). So far I have success with C++ WinRT Core application template, but not with the console application template. The code

```cpp
struct XamlApp : public winrt::Windows::UI::Xaml::ApplicationT<XamlApp>
{
    void OnLaunched(winrt::Windows::ApplicationModel::Activation::LaunchActivatedEventArgs const&)
    {
        winrt::Windows::UI::Xaml::Window::Current().Content(winrt::UWPCore::MainPage());
        winrt::Windows::UI::Xaml::Window::Current().Activate();
    }

    // Inherited via ApplicationT
    virtual void use_make_function_to_create_this_object() override {}
};

int __stdcall wWinMain(HINSTANCE, HINSTANCE, PWSTR, int)
{
    winrt::init_apartment();
    winrt::Windows::UI::Xaml::Application::Start([](auto&&){ winrt::make<XamlApp>();});
}
```

This will successfully display a window using the **Core Application** template. But using the same code (but with the normal `main` function) with the **Console Application** template it fails with `Windows.UI.Xaml.dll!00007FFAEFC26955: (caller: 00007FF720072F32) FailFast(1) tid(1680) 8000FFFF Catastrophic failure`. Looking through the `vcxproj` files doesn't seem to provide any clue of what magic visual studio does for deploying the UWP app.

Comment: The *"System XAML platform"* (which is the term I'm using here since Microsoft forget to give their UI platform a name) is available to UWP applications only. A UWP application needs to run in an app container. While MSBuild (apparently) knows how to deploy an AppX package, and the Shell (apparently) knows how to launch an AppX deployment into an AppContainer, things work as long as you stay on paved roads. In lieu of proper documentation, you'll have to piece things together. See if [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthz/implementing-an-appcontainer) helps any.

Comment: @IInspectable Any info regard to "MSBuild knows how to deploy an AppX package" and "the Shell knows how to launch an AppX deployment into an AppContainer"?